# Php code to get json data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json

Iam trying to create a JSON object out of my SQL data in PHP. How to do that?
This is my approach, which does not work so far.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$dns  = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=afreen";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
try {
    $conn = new PDO($dns, $user, $pass);
    if (!$conn) {
        echo "Not connected";
    }
    $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, name, salary from afreen');
    $query->execute();
    $registros = "[";
    while ($result = $query->fetch()) {
        if ($registros != "[") {
            $registros .= ",";
        }
        $registros .= '{"id": "' . $result["id"] . '",';
        $registros .= '"name": "' . $result["name"] . '"}';
        $registros .= '"salary": "' . $result["salary"] . '"}';
    $registros .= "]";
    echo $registros;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you try the json_encode() for this ? Why you try for unnecessary while loop.

```
$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, name, salary from afreen');
```

Then try the json_encode() to get the Data in Json format.

Sources - http://php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$dns  = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=afreen";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
try {
    $conn = new PDO($dns, $user, $pass);
    if (!$conn) {
        echo "Not connected";
    }
    $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, name, salary from afreen');
    $query->execute();
    $registros= [];
    while ($result = $query->fetch()) {

       array_push($registros,array(
                'id' =>$result["id"],
                'title' =>$result["name"],
                'salary' =>$result["salary"]
            ));
   $output = json_encode(array("product"=>$registros));
   print_r($output);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'catch' (T_CATCH) in C:\xampp\htdocs\appmarket-api\listado.php on line 25

Comment: try and catch remove and check output